# Yank range of lines to clipboard via ':' in vim

Tags: vim, editor, yank

I'm yanking range of lines to system clipboard in vim. I can do it with `51gg116"+yy`. I'd like to do it via `:` notation. I can copy to `""` register via command `:51,116y`. However, command `51,116"+y` doesn't work. How to fix the last command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:help :y` says:

```
:[range]y[ank] [x]  Yank [range] lines [into register x]. Yanking to the
                    "* or "+ registers is possible only when the
                    |+clipboard| feature is included.
```

so your answer is obviously:

```
:51,116y +
```

Your problem is that you try to use `:y`, the Ex command, as if it was `y`, the normal mode command.